# How to increase database size in Microsoft SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Express version. I have created a database name `ArcGIS`. By default, it has provided me space of 16 MB, see pic. I would like to increase the size of this database to 5 GB. How should I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the "File" page on the database setting.
Basically it starts with 8MB for the main database (rows) and 8MB for the log database.
It's usually set to increase size when needed. you might see it in "autogrowth", which is "by 64MB" by default.
Meaning... once you fill those 8MB, it's gonna increase it by 64MB... and once that's filled by another 64MB... Until the limit is reached (which by default is Unlimited, so "never").

But if you really want to manually set the size you can do so in the Size field.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer :-). Does unlimited means data is not stored in my hard drive but actually on Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: @Riz unlimited just means it will grow and expand for as long as it has storage space on your (hard) drive. You can see where the location is in the PATH field (on the right). SQL Server uses the two files for storage of the two relevant data in the database (row values and log values). And it is possible to limit how much it is allowed to grow.

Comment: Super. I have a different question now. 
I downloaded express version to connect to ArcGIS which is now connected and can import files. I also have an access to SQL Server Standard edition which I can only connect to ArcGIS but can not import files to desired SQL database in standard version. Perhaps because I am not the owner of that database. Now the files I imported to Express SQL edition, I would like to export those files to Standard SQL edition. How could I do this in a smart way? In other words, I would like the two servers to communicate each other to import/export files.

Comment: Such communication is a bit more complex. First of all you need a database user that has the permissions to write/update/delete into the (let's call it) "remote" database. Without that you can in no way transfer any information into it. For that, check with your local Database administrator who can assign the appropriate permissions to your user. Afterwards, probably linking the two databases would be the smart way to do it and create procedures that fetch and then send data to the to and from the local database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189422/how-do-i-create-and-query-linked-database-servers-in-sql-server
Linking them should be easy.

Comment: Yes I have the user permission to write/update/delete files in the remote (Standard SQL server). I just do not have ownership/admin writes. I can go to the database in "remote" server and can do all sort of thing there.
I will try to "create procedures" as you mentioned and send data to the "remote" (Standard SQL) database from local database (Express SQL). I will let you know if I am successful.

Comment: @Riz Note comments is not an appropriate place to ask new questions. If you need help with anything else, please post a new question with details on what you're trying to achieve, and where you're stuck.

Comment: @J.D. Thanks. I will make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the Express Edition of SQL Server has a licensing limit for maximum database size of 10Gb, so you won't be able to grow that database files past that size. But as you only need 5Gb you don't really have a problem (at the moment).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/315117/sql-server-express-database-size-limit-total-or-us.html

Comment: Ok 10GB is the limit. Thanks for update. The size limit can be solved if I am able to move data files to SQL Server Standard edition, where I have a database with storage limit of 1,000 GB. I am just wonder if I am able to do it either with some T-SQL queries or using Python code?

Comment: Backup & Restore should sort then when you need to